# Resize 256x256x256 numpy array into 64x64x64 numpy array. I am trying to implement a window size of 4 to average the elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a sparse 3D NumPy array (256x256x256) which I want to resize to 64x64x64 by using a moving window average. What would be the cleanest way of approaching this problem? Should I consider a 3D averaging window of 4x4x4 to solve the problem?

I started with an 1D window like below, but how should I extend to 2D or 3D efficiently?

```
def avgWindow(arr, size):
    return (arr[(n-1):] + arr[:-(n-1)])/float(size)
```

Comment: What do you mean by moving average? do you want to `bin` the data with a coarser resolution or do wou want the compute the moving average (which is the same size/shape as the original data -> this is why the average is moving)?

Comment: I'm sorry for not phrasing it correctly, I want to obtain data with a coarser resolution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bin your data into a coarser resolution, try doing it with `np.reshape` and `np.mean` along each dimension separately:

```
A = np.array([.....])
s = A.shape  # (256, 256, 256)
B = A.copy()  # be sure to save original data

# reshape last dimension into new dim and bin-size (int div for index & shape)
B = B.reshape(s[0], s[1], s[2] // 4, 4)
B = np.mean(B, axis=-1)  # computes average along last dim
B.shape # (256, 256, 64)
... # repeat for other 2 dimensions.
```

This should be reasonable fast since you're using `numpys` internal vectorization.

Add:

I'm not an expert with sparse matrices, but if it is really spars it might be useful to have a look into [scipy.sparse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a convolution, only on non-overlapping sub-matrices of size (4,4,4). Here is how you do it (probably the fastest and least memory intensive, since it shares memory and does not do extra calculations on any unnecessary sub-arrays):

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows
kernel = np.ones((4,4,4))
sub_matrices = view_as_windows(arr, kernel.shape, kernel.shape)
#Do convolution on extracted non-overlapping sub-matrices of shape (4,4,4)
output = np.einsum('ijk,mnlijk->mnl',kernel,sub_matrices)
```

If you do not wish to magnify the output to sum of points in kernel, simply divide the `output` by `kernel.size` (i.e. `output/=kernel.size`)

example:

```
arr=np.ones((256,256,256))
```

output.shape:

```
(64, 64, 64)
```

Comment: Wouldn't convolution change the characteristics of the tensor in consideration compared to pooling?

Comment: Do you mean tensor as in tensors in tensorflow? What is a _change in characteristics_?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scipy.signal.convolve` to calculate the moving average, and skip intermediate elements:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve

old_shape = 256
a = np.arange(old_shape**3).reshape(old_shape, old_shape, old_shape)
new_shape = 64 # should be an integer divider of old shape
ksize = old_shape // new_shape
kernel = np.ones((ksize, ksize, ksize)) / (ksize**3)
res = convolve(a, kernel, 'valid')[::ksize,::ksize,::ksize]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can successfully use a pooling mechanism, for example the function provided by `tensorflow` (in my case 2.1 version), have a look to the `tf` [pool function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/pool).
In this way within a window with size `(4,4,4)` you can take the maximum or the mean.

An example (note that you should reshape your input matrix adding a 0-axis dimension):

```
@tf.function
def get_local_maxima(X):
    #X has shape (1, 256,256,256)
    out = tf.nn.pool(X, window_shape=(4,4,4), pooling_type='MAX', padding='VALID') 
    return out
```

Note that you can change the `pooling_type` to `'AVG'` in order to apply an average within the window. The output will have shape `(1, 64,64,64)`, so you have to reshape again into a 3D matrix, you can simply use:

```
out = tf.squeeze(out)
```